# How to get Youtube Api Json Response

Tags: java, android, json, youtube-data-api

I have implement insert rating method in my app . I am searching more than 1 days to get the response . In [this](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate) page i have check that insert like method and json is giving response . Look [image: here] .

But i don't find any way to get the response in my app . How can i solve this ?

```
@SuppressLint("StaticFieldLeak")
class Insert extends AsyncTask<Object,Object, Object> {

    @Override
    protected Object doInBackground(Object... objects) {



        if (Email!=null){

            mCredential = GoogleAccountCredential.usingOAuth2(
                    getApplicationContext(), Arrays.asList(YouTubeScopes.YOUTUBE))
                    .setBackOff(new ExponentialBackOff());



            mCredential.setSelectedAccountName(Email);

            HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
            JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
            YouTube youtubeService = new YouTube.Builder(
                    transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
                    .setApplicationName(LikeInsertActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.app_name))
                    .build();
            // Define and execute the API request

            try {
                YouTube.Videos.Rate request = youtubeService.videos()
                        .rate(VID, "like");

                request.execute();








                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                    public void run() {


                    }
                });


            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();

            }

        }

        return null;

    }



}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As `@mavriksc` mentions `Rate.execute()` returns `Void`. This is due to the fact that all these object are based on the superclass 
[`com.google.api.services.youtube.YouTubeRequest<java.lang.Void>`](https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/youtube/v3/java/latest/com/google/api/services/youtube/YouTubeRequest.html)

However instead of the `execute` method you can use other methods defined by [`AbstractGoogleClientRequest`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest.html) which is a super class of `YouTubeRequest`.

For example [`executeUnparsed`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-api-client/latest/com/google/api/client/googleapis/services/AbstractGoogleClientRequest.html#executeUnparsed--) returns a [`com.google.api.client.HttpResponse`](https://googleapis.dev/java/google-http-client/1.30.1/com/google/api/client/http/HttpResponse.html?is-external=true) object.

So obtaining that `HttpResponse` object and checking the StatusCode vs `204` seems to be the solution you want to have.

---

Example:

```
try {
    final YouTube.Videos.Rate request = youtubeService.videos().rate(VID, "like");

    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {

            HttpResponse response = request.executeUnparsed();

            // There should be a matching constant for 204 defined somewhere, I haven't found it yet
            if (response.getStatusCode() == 204) {
                //  request successfull
            }
        }
    });
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

*Note:*
*Android forces developers to do certain (time consuming) things (like NetworkCommunication) in a background task to prevent the UI from blocking.*

Comment: let me check . :D

Comment: got this response :  com.google.api.client.http.HttpResponse@9684491

Comment: can you write an example?

Comment: I have tried this . Not worked . I am looking for the solution for 2 days.

Comment: OW man . Yes it worked . I have use the matching in runOnUiThread and it worked. Before this i direct used the method that's why app crashed .

Comment: Thanks Man . Thank you so much.

Comment: Just for reference, with what error does it crash when you not do it in the background?

Comment: Can't create handler inside thread that has not called Looper.prepare()  it happen's when i check it inside try method.

Comment: I adjusted the answer so that other users might not run into the same issue, but I am not sure how much has to be moved into the background task. Feel free to correct it if its not enough.

Answer (score 1):

The return type of Rate.execute() is Void. looking at the HTTP it seems like you get a 204 no content on a good response and an exception otherwise.
 https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/rate

Comment: So how can i check that ? Like How can i understand in app that i have liked the video?

Comment: There is no response getting method as other method.